Modifying Grafana Opentelemetry Hostmetrics Variable
I recently set up the OpenTelemetry Collector (HostMetrics) to send data to Prometheus/Mimir and are using the following Grafana dashboard (https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/20376-opentelemetry-collector-hostmetrics-node-exporter/) to view our Node host metrics. The dashboard is functioning well, and I can view my host metrics based on the example collector configuration as shown in Screenshot2
However, I have a question regarding the dashboard’s Host variable. Currently, it displays the collector pod hostname instead of the actual Kubernetes node hostname. This creates issues, particularly when the collector pod recycles, as the dropdown continues to list old, non-existent names.
In Screenshot 1, you can see we’re running the collector as a DaemonSet to scrape host metrics. In Screenshot 2, you’ll notice the pod hostname has been assigned in the Grafana Dashboard host variable.
Could you please guide me on how to configure the OpenTelemetry Collector to use the node hostname (e.g., ip-10xxxxxx-.internal) instead of the dynamic pod hostname?
UPDATES 11-Oct-2024
I managed to extract the node name.  I can now populate the node by adding the following processors.  Now come another problem, when I select any of the item in the list, the chart doesn't show anything.  Seems like it can't select any thing at all.  Hope someone could point me to a right direction.  Thanks.
    resource/agent:
      attributes:
        - action: upsert
          key: service.namespace
          value: agent
        - action: upsert
          key: service.hostname
          value: ${env:K8S_NODE_NAME}
    attributes/agent:
      actions:
        - key: service.namespace
          action: upsert
          value: agent
        - key: service.hostname
          action: upsert
          value: ${env:K8S_NODE_NAME}



Screenshot1

Screenshot2

Hostmetrics Collector Configuration
exporters:
  otlphttp/mimir:
    endpoint: http://mimir:9009/otlp

receivers:
  # otelcontribcol metrics + host metrics
  prometheus/agent:
    config:
      scrape_configs:
        - job_name: otel-collector
          scrape_interval: 10s
          static_configs:
            - targets: [0.0.0.0:8888]
  hostmetrics/agent:
    collection_interval: 10s
    scrapers:
      cpu:
        metrics:
          system.cpu.logical.count:
            enabled: true
      memory:
        metrics:
          system.memory.utilization:
            enabled: true
          system.memory.limit:
            enabled: true
      load:
      disk:
      filesystem:
        metrics:
          system.filesystem.utilization:
            enabled: true
      network:
      paging:
      processes:
      process:
        mute_process_user_error: true
        metrics:
          process.cpu.utilization:
            enabled: true
          process.memory.utilization:
            enabled: true
          process.threads:
            enabled: true
          process.paging.faults:
            enabled: true

processors:
  batch/agent:
  resource/agent:
    attributes:
      - action: upsert
        key: service.namespace
        value: agent
  attributes/agent:
    actions:
      - key: service.namespace
        action: upsert
        value: agent
      - key: service.name
        action: upsert
        value: otel-collector
  resourcedetection/system:
    detectors: ["system"]
    system:
      hostname_sources: ["os"]
  transform:
    metric_statements:
      - context: datapoint
        statements:
          - set(attributes["host.name"], resource.attributes["host.name"])
          - set(attributes["process.command"], resource.attributes["process.command"])
          - set(attributes["process.command_line"], resource.attributes["process.command_line"])
          - set(attributes["process.executable.name"], resource.attributes["process.executable.name"])
          - set(attributes["process.executable.path"], resource.attributes["process.executable.path"])
          - set(attributes["process.owner"], resource.attributes["process.owner"])
          - set(attributes["process.parent_pid"], resource.attributes["process.parent_pid"])
          - set(attributes["process.pid"], resource.attributes["process.pid"])

service:
  telemetry:
    metrics:
      level: detailed

  pipelines:
    metrics/agent:
      receivers: [prometheus/agent, hostmetrics/agent]
      processors: [attributes/agent, resourcedetection/system, transform, batch/agent]
      exporters: [otlphttp/mimir]


Ok, i finally managed to get it working.  Updating the datapoint host.name to use the node name.  That solved the problem.
  transform:
    metric_statements:
      - context: datapoint
        statements:
          - set(attributes["host.name"], "${env:K8S_NODE_NAME}")

